# Show that the transformation is bijective if the matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given a transformation:
\begin{equation}
T: \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, \quad \mathbf{C} \mapsto (\mathbf{AC})^T
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A}$ is $m \times n$.

I am supposed to show that if $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible then the transformation $T$ is bijective. I've already shown that is is injective, just showed that $T(\mathbf{X})=T(\mathbf{Y}) \implies \mathbf{X}=\mathbf{Y}$, however I am not too sure about how to show that it is surjective.

Comment: Non-square matrices are not invertible (invertibility is defined only for square matrices): so, what do you mean?

Comment: @Crostul It just means that $m=n$ as was pointed out below, but thank you for your interest in helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then $m=n$.

Since you have proved that $T$ is injective, it follows from the rank-nullity theorem that $T$ is surjective because the two spaces have the same dimension (and $T$ is linear).